# Having trouble understanding the scansion for the second line of the Aeneid

Tags: scansion, aeneis

I've just begun to learn scansion, and I'm using the Aeneid to practice - sadly, I'm stuck on line two ("Italiam, fato profugus, Laviniaque venit"). To make a long story short, I ended up looking up the solution, and it turns out that the last 'i' in Lavinia doesn't count as a vowel: "Ītălĭ|ām fāt|ō prŏfŭg|ūs Lāv|īniăquĕ| vēnĭt" Why is this? Is this consonantal 'i', and if that's the case, why? I was taught that an 'i' after a consonant was usually a vowel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a tricky one, when you're just starting out with scansion! You're right that *Lāvīnia* would normally be four syllables: *Lā-vī-ni-a*.

However, there's a process in poetry known as *synizesis* (from the Greek συνίζησις), where two vowels next to each other can turn into a diphthong when the meter requires it. It's not especially common, but has a long and illustrious pedigree: the very first line of the Iliad has an *eō* (εω) that need to be pronounced as a single syllable. (In the same foot as this *ia*, actually—I'd never noticed that before.)

So in this instance, synizesis turns the word into *Lā-vīn-ja*, three syllables, for the sake of the meter. You won't run into this very often, but it's a good tool to keep in mind when a line just won't quite scan. This isn't the only time you'll see it in Vergil!

Comment: That makes sense. This can happen, you're saying, with any two vowels that aren't diphthongs?
Also, why is the 'i' in 'venit' short? I thought that the last foot was always a spondee in Dactylic Hexameter.

Comment: @Eli Regarding _venit_, I'd recommend asking that as another question, because it deserves more than just a comment! But yes, it can theoretically happen with any vowels; some combinations are much more frequent than others, and synizesis is rare enough that I'm guessing some pairs are entirely unattested, but I'm not aware of any combinations being actually _forbidden_.